# Как мигрировать существующий проект , созданный с помощью create-react-app в микрофронтенд на базе библиотеки single-spa?

Tags: reactjs

Пробовал следовать шаблону из статьи https://medium.com/litslink/how-to-create-react-micro-frontends-from-scratch-using-single-spa-framework-in-examples-592c7f63bedf . Но ничего не получилось у меня.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Если у кого то были такие примеры , поделитесь ими пожалуйста.